# MongoDB Query Performance Analysis

Tags: java, mongodb

I have done a reasonable amount of searching about getting information on slow queries, but the information I've found seems to indicate that the data you can get out of the db is rather limited.

I would like to know for a query how much time is spent waiting on locks, which index was used for the query, how much time was spent waiting/getting from disk, and how much time was spent processing (of particular interest for aggregation framework performance).

I wanted to check and see if people here had any suggestions for measuring these parameters, and/or if it was even possible.

Thanks in advance. :)

*Edit.  I tend to use the java mongo driver, if that matters.

Comment: nice questions :) I was also interested in knowing how to check performance on aggregation queries and more.

Comment: You cannnot reliably measure performance of aggregation queries yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504 however you could write a simple JS script that runs the command on the master to get a distance of time, but it is not really that useful or accurate. These parts: "how much time was spent waiting/getting from disk" will need to be picked up by you, you do have mongotop and other tools for this but they are more collection/global based: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongotop/

Comment: Your comment confirms my 1st paragraph. :S :(

The http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/current-op/ tool gives some information but has to be run in an awkward manner.  The system profiler is semi-useful but really stops short of being helpful.

Comment: You can get information about the indices of a query from the explain command: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/explain/#_S_explain  Though AFAIK it can't be directly used in an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Indeed it is very hard to measure MongoDBs "internals" of lock/write/pages/virtual memory/RAM/IO etc on a per query basis, I'll keep looking for something. Would be good if it could pipe currentOp() out like an explain, hmm maybe there is a feature request there

Comment: Good comment Mjhm.  The explain is definitely the closest thing I've found, and at the very least it can be used to get details on the first 'match' operation you might have in your pipeline.

Comment: Have you tried to use profiler? (with db.setProfilingLevel) It has some hints on locking time. It also works for aggregation framework queries but only for the whole query not for individual steps. Also you can use db.serverStatus() to get some information but it is global.

Comment: Yes, I have turned the profiling, but like you said it isn't super-detailed. :S

    Good list of suggestions  + ways to use them.  Judging from the feedback so far, it looks like I might have to go and dig around to see if I should put together a feature request. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something that may not be obvious if you haven't looked into `mongod` logs - all operations that take longer than "slow ms" threshold (100ms is the default but you can change it) are logged into mongod log file.

Here is an example of what it might look like and how to read it:

`update training.scores 
 query: { score: { $lte: 90.0 } } 
 update: { $set: { grade: "B" } } 
 nscanned:4876 
 nmoved:2438 
 nupdated:2438 
 keyUpdates:0 
 numYields: 2 
 locks(micros) w:400877
 235ms`

You can see what some of these fields mean [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/#output-reference), but the ones you are interested in are locks, numYields, nmoved and nupdated as well as nscanned - also scanAndOrder (that's whether a sort used an index or had to be done in memory).

I recommend reviewing that docs page about what information you can get from the system.profile collection and also from the mongod logs to help in investigating performance of your cluster.

Comment: Hmmmm...the scanAndOrder one I haven't seen come up before I'll keep my eye out for it in the logs.

Comment: scanAndOrder:1 is the bad one - you can also see it in .explain() as scanAndOrder:true.  you can see time spent waiting for locks by subtracting locks time (/1000 since it's in microseconds) from total time taken (last field in milliseconds).

Comment: Do you know how much of this is available through the drivers? or does it have to be done manually on the server side?

Comment: if you turn on db profiling (db.setProfilingLevel(1,X) <- X is millisecond threshold then there will be a collection called system.profile and you can query for slow queries in it from any driver or mongo shell.

Comment: yes. I've used that. I just wasn't sure if some of this would be directly available as part of the aggregation response object or something along those lines.